# Error gráfico en JPanel

Tags: java, netbeans, interfaz-gráfica

Tengo un bug al aplicar este efecto de trasparencia en un jPanel, creo que el error es por la manera en que estoy aplicando el efecto (simplista) pero no estoy seguro, cuando ponga el raton por primera vez sobre el panel este refleja donde tengo el mouse.

```
Color original;
Color nuevo;
original = new Color(0, 0, 0, 80);
nuevo = new Color(50,28,89);
```

Cambio el color del panel si el mouse entra y cuando salga lo vuelvo otra vez como estaba.

```
private void jLabel1MouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        jPanel3.setBackground(original);
    }                                    

    private void jLabel1MouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        jPanel3.setBackground(nuevo);
    }
```

[Gif del error](https://i.gyazo.com/814f89f5e82b282e2a0a86812124949c.mp4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre que se trata de un bug que ocurre ya que un JPanel no tiene puede ser transparente.
La solución es dibujarlo y luego si aplicar la capa RGBA.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
 g.setColor(getBackground());
 Rectangle r = g.getClipBounds();
 g.fillRect(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);
 super.paintComponent(g);
```

Solución encontrada aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059020/transparent-jpanel/10059218